# Statefulsets without pvc and claim template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset, kubernetes-pvc

I want to use statefulsets only because  I need identifiable pods like pod0 pod1 etc.However, I don't need any storage. Can I do away without using any storage and still creGe statefulsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its ok, weird but ok.
Kubernetes will not stop creating the pods because of not having any pvc template.